# sys/socket missing member for msgdr: msg_control, msg_controllen, msg_flags

Tags: c, sockets, c89, unix-socket

I'm trying to write a little Client-Server application using the UNIX DOMAIN SOCKETS.

I'm using the `msghdr` for the `sendmsg`/`recvmsg` but when I compile the following code, it gives me the following error:

```
include <sys/socket.h>
...
struct msghdr mh;
struct cmsghdr *cmp;
union{
    struct cmsghdr cm;
    char ctrl[sizeof(struct cmsghdr) + sizeof(int)];
} ctrlu;
...
mh.msg_name = NULL;
mh.msg_namelen = 0;
mh.msg_iov = iov;
mh.msg_iovlen = 1;
mh.msg_control = ctrlu.ctrl;
mh.msg_controllen = sizeof(ctrlu);
mh.msg_flags = 0;
```

Error message:

> gcc s.c -o s -lsocket
>
> s.c: In function `main':
>
> s.c:59: error: structure has no member named `msg_control'
>
> s.c:60: error: structure has no member named `msg_controllen'
>
> s.c:61: error: structure has no member named `msg_flags'
>
> *** Error code 1

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bug in Solaris, it works fine in Linux. (You didn't specify the OS exactly, but I saw you used `-lsocket` compiler option, which is not necessary in Linux)

Comment: Yes, the bug was observed in Solaris 11.3, and Solaris 11.4 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue (i.e. `msg_flags` not being a member of the `msghdr` structure) when trying to compile the C++ project Boost.Asio on Solaris 11.3 using the default compiler settings of the IDE in Oracle Developer Studio 12.6. Boost.Asio's build system seems to work around the problem [by providing these options to the compiler](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/test/Jamfile.v2#L34-L37):

```
-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D__EXTENSIONS__
```

and these to the linker:

```
-lsocket -lnsl
```

My problem was solved after I added these settings to my project in the IDE.

I'm not sure exactly how it worked, but it may have something to do with the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54772/socket-3head.html) saying that `msg_flags`, `msg_control` and `msg_controllen` are available only in the "libxnet interface" and not the "libsocket interface".

Also notable how the Samba project dealt with this: https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11053 (they `#define`-ed `_XPG4_2` and `__EXTENSIONS__`).